# Google Plus Sharing Does not get Description and Image

Tags: google-plus, socialshare

I am try to integrate google plus sharing and I have created a url i.e

http://prod.outfastsource.com/ofscmsapi/app/sharing?fbTitle=This%20is%20Title&fbDesc=This%20is%20Description&ogImageMetaTag=http://prod.outfastsource.com/images/blog/hire-outsourced-development-help.png&returnUrl=http://prod.outfastsource.com/blog/7-things-to-consider-before-you-hire-outsourced-development-help

When I have tried this on google test tool i.e

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fprod.outfastsource.com%2Fofscmsapi%2Fapp%2Fsharing%3FfbTitle%3DThis%2520is%2520Title%26fbDesc%3DThis%2520is%2520Description%26ogImageMetaTag%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fprod.outfastsource.com%2Fimages%2Fblog%2Fhire-outsourced-development-help.png%26returnUrl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fprod.outfastsource.com%2Fblog%2F7-things-to-consider-before-you-hire-outsourced-development-help

Then fetch all information fine i. Title and Description and Image.

But When I am try to share this url like this

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://prod.outfastsource.com/ofscmsapi/app/sharing?fbTitle=ThisisTitle&fbDesc=ThisisDescription&ogImageMetaTag=http://prod.outfastsource.com/images/blog/hire-outsourced-development-help.png&returnUrl=http://prod.outfastsource.com/blog/7-things-to-consider-before-you-hire-outsourced-development-help

Then It does not show the Description and Image.

Can any one help me Please.

Comment: The URL you are testing returns a 404 error. It will need to return a 200 OK for it to work.

Comment: I have changed url and Now it working fine. Thanks